# How to Inject daoFactory into NHibernate EventListener

Tags: c#, nhibernate, design-patterns, ioc-container

I need to Inject some global service (daoFactory) into EventListenet subscribed on PostUpdate event. I`ve read that it is possible to do this way:

```
public class YourPostInsertListener : IPostInsertEventListener
{
private readonly IPersistentAuditor auditor;

public YourPostInsertListener(IPersistentAuditor auditor)
{
    this.auditor = auditor;
}

public void OnPostInsert(PostInsertEvent @event)
```

But this code just throws exception: no parameterless constructor was specified for EventListener. And this is understandable behavior, because I haven`t added my service to any container. So how can I specify the IoC contauner in NHibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IoC that I've been using is Ninject.  The best way I found so far is to take advantage of the ServiceLocator provdided by the Microsoft Patterns and Practices guys:

```
internal class YourPostInsertListener : IPostInsertEventListener
{
    IKernel Kernel
    {
        get 
        { 
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IKernel>(); 
        }
    }

    IPersistentAuditor 
    {
       get
       {
            return Kernel.Get<IPersistentAuditor>();
       }
    }
    // ... Rest of class
}
```

In the class that sets up your IoC container you would do this:

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider( () => new NinjectServiceLocator( kernel ) );
```